# Failed to invoke apoc procedure (that was working just a minute ago)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

IS IT POSSIBLE FOR APOC TO SELECTIVELY CRASH ON JUST ONE PROCEDURE?

```
MATCH (n:Node) 
RETURN apoc.temporal.format(n.DT, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

was returning **"14/12/23"** (via neo4j browser)

Then I ran query through php client, and it returns

**"Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke function `apoc.temporal.format`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"**

Then I run it again via neo4j browser and get the same error. So the browser shows working query, then a handful of minutes later shows the exact same query yielding error. I am puzzled.

```
CALL apoc.help("apoc")
```

returns long list that includes:

**"function    apoc.temporal.format    apoc.temporal.format(input, format) | Format a temporal value"**

Meanwhile, a bunch of other apoc functions seem to be working fine...

Rebooting the database does not fix it.

MY QUESTION: HOW DO I "REBOOT" APOC OR MAKE THIS PROCEDURE WORK AGAIN, AND HOW TO ENSURE THIS DOES NOT HAPPEN DURING DEPLOYMENT?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there now some nodes missing the `DT` property? Does this query return anything?:  `MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.DT IS NULL RETURN n`.

Comment: Sorry this fell through the cracks with the holidays. The DT property is not missing.  I am not sure what I did but it's working again.